# Why does this throw a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, string, exception

I've made a GUI in Java that takes in unsorted/organized HTML code and organizes it nicely. I rewrote a section of code and now I get a string out of bounds exception from this if statement.... No idea why/how though.

Code:

```
if (result.charAt(result.length() - 1) == '\n')
```

Comment: Please always post the stacktrace with your question. But likely, `result` has a length of 0.

Comment: Now tell us what the value of `result` is.

Comment: if the string is empty, then you're asking for `charAt(-1)`

Comment: `result` is probably an empty string. So you are basically trying to find  `charAt(-1)`.

Comment: ( stringA - x ) will throw that error IF StringA.lenght() < x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works just fine, check your input string, if **length of `result` is 0**.

Also you can add a new condition to avoid this issue:

```
if (result.length() > 0 && result.charAt(result.length() - 1) == '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this code:

```
if (result != null && result.endsWith("\n"))
```